# Jenkins Chuck Norris Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I setup Jenkins for a CI server and everything seems to be working great. So I thought I would install the Chuck Norris Plugin for some humor. I installed the plugin using the plugin manager but I don't see the option to activate it.

Has anyone done this is there a dependency I need to install to get this to work?

Comment: didn't know the plugin, thanks for this

Comment: Here's part of the humor:  http://codesqueeze.com/the-ultimate-top-25-chuck-norris-the-programmer-jokes/

Answer (score 25):

You can activate it on the job configuration page.  Select "Add post-build action" -> "Activate Chuck Norris".

Answer (score 1):

Just run [next script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Activate+Chuck+Norris+Plugin) in jenkins script concole (`http://your_server/jenkins/script` or Manage Jenkins > Script Console):

```
import jenkins.model.*


for(item in Jenkins.instance.items) {
     println("job $item.name")
     item.publishersList.replace(new  hudson.plugins.chucknorris.CordellWalkerRecorder());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to activate the plugin after I installed it. Most plugins I have used automatically activate. I'm not sure why this one didn't. But that was the fix.

Comment: You don't activate Chuck Norris...he deactivates you!

Answer (score 0):

Activating the Chuck Norris plugin in a **pipeline** is slightly more tricky. I use this method of doing it in my groovy pipeline code:

```
node('my-build-node') {

    try {
        stage('First stage') {
            // stage steps
        }

        stage('Second stage') {
            // stage steps
        }
        // etc. for as many stages as you want in the try block
    } finally {
        // Call Chuck Norris
        step([$class: 'CordellWalkerRecorder'])
    }
}
```

By putting the call to the Chuck Norris plugin in the finally section, it will be called for success or failure, so you always get wisdom from the Great Man himself.