# Why does Chuck Norris show up with his picture and humorous comments in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I've been working with Jenkins for several years now, but I have no idea why Chuck Norris is featured with comments on the server?  I think it's funny, but I don't see the connection between a CI server and a Martial Artist?

Does anyone know why he is there and why he was picked over some other well known martial artist, like Jet Li?

Comment: Did you maybe install the Chuck Norris plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571637/jenkins-chuck-norris-plugin?rq=1

Comment: No, it was already on the server when I got there.  I was told it was part of the regular Jenkins install.  I've seen it everywhere I've used Jenkins.  I'm curious about everything and this piqued my interest.

Comment: For one thing, Chuck Norris (the meme, at least, unsure about the real one) is a renowned programmer with superpowers: http://codesqueeze.com/the-ultimate-top-25-chuck-norris-the-programmer-jokes/

Comment: Time to have  [John Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)  plugin, then

Comment: Here's all you need to know:  http://codesqueeze.com/the-ultimate-top-25-chuck-norris-the-programmer-jokes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because somebody installed the [Chuck Norris](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ChuckNorris+Plugin) plugin for Jenkins.
This is definitely *not* included in Jenkins by default, but it has been installed on around 1 out of every 20 Jenkins setups.

There isn't a Jet Li plugin, but if you're more into cryptographers than martial artists, there is a similar plugin for [Bruce Schneier](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BruceSchneier+Plugin).

More generically (and more scary when a build fails), there's the [Emotional Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Emotional+Jenkins+Plugin) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Chuck Norris plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ChuckNorris+Plugin) for more info on configuring the plugin.

Comment: how to use it on jenkins pipeline instead of a maven on jenkins ?